# Angular promises and two methods

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two different methods, one which is used to trigger something, and another which is listener for response. I want to be able to call that triggering method that way so that next it's not called before I receive all the data in my second listener callback method. How can I do that?

I tried like this:

```
var doCommand = function(command) {
    var d = $q.defer();
    //I want to call this one only when previous command is finished,
    //and that's done in method bellow...
    myApp.callTriggeringMethod(command);  

    myApp.myEventListener(function(){
        //on successful callback
        alert('One command done');
        d.resolve(result); //I want here to enable next command execution
    }, function(){
       //on error
})
    return d.promise;
}

$q.all([
        doCommand("A")      
        ,doCommand("B")         
        ,doCommand("C")     
        ]).then(function(data) {
                alert('ALL DONE');
               //TODO: something...
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `$q.all` just chain your promises with `then`:

```
doCommand("A")
    .then(_ => doCommand("B"))
    .then(_ => doCommand("C"))
    .then(function(data) {
            alert('ALL DONE');
           //TODO: something...
    });
```

You might have to change your functions so they can take the resolved value from the previous promise and pass it on to the next. This all depends on which data you want to have in your final callback.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you correctly you have dependant calls and wants the second call to wait until the first has finished.. You would write it like this:

```
doCommand('A')
  .then(doCommand('B'))
  .then(doCommand('C'))
  .then( function(dataFromC){ console.log('all done')  } )
```

what you were doing above was a parallell fetch where all data would arrive at the same time. Hope that helps

Comment: Yes, that's what I want, but I want to mark that this doCommand is finished in my custom event listener onSuccess callback. I just tried like you suggested, but again this `doCommand` was triggered multiple times before I got any response in my `myEventListener` success function. Do I need to rearange something there as well?

Comment: can't invoke `doCommand()` in argument of `then()` .. it doesn't return a  function which is what argument of `then` needs to be